# Sort List by Popularity

Tags: list, custom-list, discussion-board

As an organisation we have a discussion board. 
We also have a list of presentations.

There does not seem to be a way to sort either of these by 'popularity' out of the box with Sharepoint.

**Is there a way for a list and a discussion board to be configured to be sorted by 'popularity'?**    Ideally looking for an answer that does not involve any customisation.  Would consider external plugins.

I would envisage that popularity could be quantified by number of views (preferred) or by encouraging staff to rate items and then sort on the rating score.

I believe this is related to [this Q](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/cqwp-sort-items-based-on-popularity) although not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation and would have thought this feature would be present in a product such as this.

Your link was quite interesting although like you I didn't really want to have to delve into too much code (especially JavaScript) to get such a simple thing working like this.

I basically came up with a crude method myself of creating a custom column titled popularity (you can hide this later is you don't want it shown).  I set the column to the number type.  I then modified the view to sort via this column

I then booted up SharePoint Designer (SPD) and created a workflow to increment the number column for the item (when modified) when clicked.

It works fine although there are some pitfalls:
1.) There is a few seconds lag as the workflows starts and completes.
2.) If a second person views/modifies the item before the first persons workflow is completed then the incremental number does not change.

These pitfalls however are very minor and allows me to sort effectively.

Hope this is of some help

Regards

Ryan D Hale